# Workflow Service Error

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am trying to call a workflow service from an asp .net application and i am getting the following error. Any ideas or help pleasE?

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The operation could not be performed because WorkflowInstance '2dde84a5-da6e-4951-a404-d659fb23b5bd' has terminated. Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at ServiceReference1.IService.TestSimple(String& out2, String input) at ServiceReference1.ServiceClient.TestSimple(String& out2, String input) in c:\Users\marios\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website2\dd8a5636\5104a2dc\App_WebReferences.yntecwjx.0.cs:line 51 at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\marios\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite2\Default.aspx.cs:line 34

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the workflow aborted before the reply was sent.  Check out my blog post for help.
[Troubleshooting Workflow Services with diagnostic logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/12/16/troubleshooting-workflow-services-with-diagnostic-logging.aspx)